# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Transact__'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Transactions_ID'. The duplicate key value is (1001)

Tags: sql

When I am trying to insert execute the table and I am getting that error. And when I try to insert more rows into `Employee_in` I get an error

> The number of columns for each row in a table value constructor must be the same

```
CREATE DATABASE EmployeeDatabase

USE EmployeeDatabase

CREATE TABLE Employee_In
(
    EmployeeID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    EmployeeName CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    EmployeeCountry CHAR(30)NOT NULL,
    EmployeeSalary INT NOT NULL
)

USE EmployeeDatabase
GO

INSERT INTO Employee_In (EmployeeID, EmployeeName, EmployeeCountry, EmployeeSalary)
VALUES (1001, 'Sundar', 'USA', 125000),
       (1002, 'Satya', 'CANADA', 120000);

SELECT * FROM Employee_In

CREATE TABLE Transactions_ID
(
    TransactionID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    EmployeeID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employee_In(EmployeeID),
    PostalDate VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Amount VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    Description CHAR(25),
);

USE EmployeeDatabase
GO

INSERT INTO Transactions_ID (TransactionID, EmployeeID, PostalDate, Amount)
VALUES ('1001','1001','2020-04-07','20000')
```

Comment: **WHY** is `Amount` a `VARCHAR(40)` column  - that should really be some numerical datatype. And **why** is `PostalDate` a `VARCHAR(20)` column - that really should be `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)`

Answer (score 0):

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Transact__'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Transactions_ID'. The duplicate key value is (1001)

This means you already have a value 1001 for the PK TransactionID in your table, most likely from and earlier insert.

```
INSERT INTO Transactions_ID (TransactionID, EmployeeID, PostalDate, Amount)
VALUES ('1001', '1001', '2020-04-07', '20000')
```

Here you are trying to insert string in columns with a datatype int... this should be:

```
INSERT INTO Transactions_ID (TransactionID, EmployeeID, PostalDate, Amount)
VALUES (1001, 1001, '2020-04-07', '20000')
```

Good luck!